# How do I install the Visual Studio 2010 Shell to use SQL Server Data Tools?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've downloaded and installed the Visual Studio 2010 Express products (Visual C#, Visual Basic, Visual C++, and Visual Web Developer) on a machine running Windows 7 Professional and a few SQL Server instances of SQL Server 2012 Express.  All of the Visual Studio 2010 products are running well.

However, isn't there an additional shell that needs to be installed?  Shouldn't it come with the product set?  The reason I ask is that I'm working through a book titled Microsoft SQL Server 2012 that uses elements of Visual Studio to illustrate some SQL Server principles; specifically, the use of SQL Server Data Tools.  SQL Server Data Tools was not an available feature during the install of SQL Server 2012 Express.

The exercise is related to using the SQL Server Development Settings of SQL Server Data Tools to create a SQL Server Database Project.

Comment: You dont. You install SQL Management Studio Basic. (which is free)

Comment: Thank you for your input, leppie.  I found where to download SQL Server Data Tools: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650014.

Answer (score 5):

I found the following link to download SQL Server Data Tools 2010 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650014.